# Layout is hanged during asynctask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I am new to android development.
I am trying to load some network data which I want to do asynchronously such that splash screen shows up till the network operation completes.Now when I am running the belo the splash screen doesnt shows up rather it shows a blank screen with the title bar in hanged state.

I have marked this activity as LAUNCHER in manifest file as well. Can you tell me what would be the right way to it?

Here is my code for splash screen.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            try{

                        AsyncTask<Void, Void, HukumNamaDetails> async=new URLReader(splashScreen).execute();
                        hdetails=async.get();

                        splashScreen.saveImage(currdate);


                    }

         catch(InterruptedException e) {} catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                System.out.println("In finally");
                finish();

                //start a new activity
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("hdetails", new HukumNamaDetails(hdetails.getHukumnama_punjabi()
                    ,hdetails.getPunjabi_vyakhya(),hdetails.getEnglish_translation()));
                i.setClass(splashScreen, Daily_HukumNama.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }

//Function that will handle the touch
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        synchronized(splashTread){
                splashTread.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    return true;
}


}
```

Thanks 
Amandeep

Comment: because you are calling [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) which make UI Thread wait until `doInBackground` execution not complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using AsyncTask can be little dicey :**

**1.** Use the **onPreExecute()** of AsyncTask to **launch** the **splash** screen.

**2.** Do your **work** in **doInBackground()** of AsyncTask. **Do not try** any **UI stuff** in here.

**3.** **Remove** the **splash** screen in **onPostExecute()** of AsyncTask as your background stuff will be done by then.

To start the AsyncTask, just call execute() using the AsyncTask object's reference.

Note : Calling **get()** at this point of time is unnecessary from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `get()` function will cause your UI thread to wait until the computation is complete.  Dont call the `get()` method. Instead do all your postprocessing in the `onPostExecute()` method of the `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Don't call `get()`. Override `onPostExecute()` in your AsyncTask to handle any UI updates resulting from the operation. Calling `get()` will cause the UI thread to block.